# Add a .cpp file into a MakeFile project

Tags: file, makefile, addition, gnu

How can I add a file (e.g .cpp or .h) into a makefile project, so that I can use command $make ?

Comment: Hey oCodaa, it is NOT my mean and you with your editing, change the my mean, it is shamefulness ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Name the file Makefile or makefile

Then you can run
$ make

or

$make hello

or
Essentially though, this is the format you want:

```
all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
     gcc main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello


clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

Comment: This is so simple and I familiar with it, My Question is about large projects (e.g. agent2d-x.x.x at rctools.sourceforge.jp ) which we can NOT create a MakeFile manually, So we have to use from autoscan then autoconf and so on, and after this process we have a MakeFile which created as automatically that are much more complex than your answer, and my question is that: How we can add a file to this automatically created MakeFile?